# Returning an object from a method

Tags: java

I have defined a method called "findRegion()" with a return type "Screen". Eventhough at the end of the my method I return a "Screen" object, my eclipse IDE still shows an error regarding return type mismatch. The method is as follows:

```
public Screen findRegion(){
        try{
            Screen screen = new Screen();
            int x = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getX() - 10; 
            int y = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getY() - 10; 
            int w = x + 370;
            int h = y + 300;
            screen.setRect(x,y,w,h);
            return screen;
        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The objective of this code is to create a region with the respective dimensions.
Kindly suggest the errors in my code.
Thank You

Comment: In case of error function will skip the try block "return statement" and wont return anything. I believe this is the problem.

Comment: The key is that at the end of *one path* of your method, you return a `Screen` object. If your code throws an exception, what will be returned then?

Comment: You are not returning anything in case of an exception.

Comment: If an exception is thrown nothing will be returned, as the **return** statement is in the try block.

Comment: " Eventhough at the end of the my method I return a "Screen" object" this is simply not correct.

Comment: Thank You all. The code worked as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are catching an exception, then you need to return something from there too. Alternatively you can have like below

```
public Screen findRegion(){
    Screen screen = null;
    try{
        screen = new Screen();
        int x = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getX() - 10; 
        int y = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getY() - 10; 
        int w = x + 370;
        int h = y + 300;
        screen.setRect(x,y,w,h);

    }
    catch(FindFailed e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return screen;

}
```

Comment: @user3796719 - The important question is ... do you *understand why*?

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because of your try-catch block. What if an error occurs (`FindFailed`)? Then you don't return anything!

```
try {
  Screen screen = new Screen();
  int x = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getX() - 10; 
  int y = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getY() - 10; 
  int w = x + 370;
  int h = y + 300;
  screen.setRect(x,y,w,h);
  return screen;
} catch (FindFailed e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  // what to do if this happens?
  // proper error handling must be done here. Either return 'null' or propagate the error to the calling method!
}
// you can even make a return statement here if it is more convenient for you
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method must have a default return statement.

(see the comment for return statement)

```
public String findRegion(){
        try{
            Screen screen = new Screen();
            int x = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getX() - 10; 
            int y = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getY() - 10; 
            int w = x + 370;
            int h = y + 300;
            screen.setRect(x,y,w,h);
            return screen;   // may not come here if any brakage before
        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Best practice is having only one return statement for the method. Then your code turns into

```
public String findRegion(){
        Screen screen= null;
        try{
            screen = new Screen();
            int x = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getX() - 10; 
            int y = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getY() - 10; 
            int w = x + 370;
            int h = y + 300;
            screen.setRect(x,y,w,h);
        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return screen;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your screen object before try block(you can initialize it in catch) and return it after catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not returning anything if the `FindFailed` exception occurs, that's why eclipse is showing `return type mismatch`.

You should do this type of code like :

```
public Screen findRegion(){
    Screen screen = null; //initialize your variable here with null
    try{
        screen = new Screen();
        int x = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getX() - 10; 
        int y = screen.find("C:\\Users\\skhan\\Desktop\\Images\\VVX500\\Capture2.PNG").getY() - 10; 
        int w = x + 370;
        int h = y + 300;
        screen.setRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
    catch(FindFailed e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return screen; //return screen object if all goes well or null if any exception occurs.
}
```

> **Note :** looks like the `FindFailed` is your custom `Exception`, you should write your custom exception class name ends with Exception (it reduces confusion and looks like an Exception)